# django admin URL conflict with slug in URL

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to redirect `news` to `http://localhost/<CATEGORY>/`. But Django admin does not work anymore. How I can fix this in `urls.py`?

```
url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Django tries to find `admin` category and raise error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `urls.py` something like this. So that, it can return `http://localhost/admin/` at first.

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
```

Comment: `‍DoesNotExist at /admin/ Category matching query does not exist`

Comment: Sorry dude. that's work fine. I change admin row position to top of urls.py and works fine. thanks.